# Смысл словосочетания "эксплуатируемых и строящихся" в контексте.

Tags: этимология, семантика, фразеология

Есть следующее предложение, взятое из закона:
*Составлению декларации безопасности гидротехнических сооружений при их вводе в эксплуатацию после завершения строительства, реконструкции или капитального ремонта, а также эксплуатируемых и строящихся гидротехнических сооружений предшествует обследование гидротехнических сооружений, которое организуется их собственником или эксплуатирующей организацией, с обязательным участием представителей органа надзора.*

Помогите пожалуйста определить что имеется ввиду под "эксплуатируемых и строящихся" и каким правилом это регулируется. То есть, указывают ли авторы на то, что это объекты которые *одновременно и строятся и эксплуатируются* или же это продолжение перечисления, в котором эти слова *не связаны* между собой. (т.е. два раздельных условия - при стройке, эксплуатации).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Помогите пожалуйста определить что имеется ввиду под "эксплуатируемых и строящихся" и каким правилом это регулируется.

Это, пожалуй, не к нам. Лингвистическая экспертиза - дело ответственное, трудоемкое и абы кем не проводится. Трактовать законы могут юристы, экспертизу проводить - квалифицированные лингвисты. Если что, могу кинуть адресок, но там платно, разумеется.

Впрочем, лично я не вижу в данном случае каких-либо существенных причин для разночтений. Даже если фраза и составлена несколько коряво, смысл очевиден. Обследование **всегда** предшествует составлению декларации безопасности. Будь то строящееся, эксплуатируемое или вводимое в эксплуатацию сооружение. После первичного строительства, ремонта, реконструкции и проч. Но если за Вашим вопросом действительно стоит какой-то предполагаемый юридический казус, опишите ситуацию подробнее, не думаю, что здесь что-то сложное.

ЗЫ Кстати, а в законе точно нет запятой после "а также эксплуатируемых и строящихся гидротехнических сооружений"? Это, собственно, ничего не меняет в трактовке, просто мне кажется, она здесь была бы вполне логична и, возможно, сняла бы все вопросы понимания.

//--------
Добавлено.
Я подумал, что не дал прямого ответа. Попробую исправиться.
Здесь грамматическая неоднозначность, формально допустимы обе трактовки.

Т.е. с точки зрения формальной грамматики фразу можно понимать двояко: 
а) Либо сюда относятся сооружения, которые либо эксплуатируются, либо строятся, либо одновременно строятся и эксплуатируются. Т.е. **любое сооружение, для которого выполняется хотя бы одно из перечисленных условий**.   
б) Либо речь идет только о тех, которые **одновременно** и эксплуатируются, и строятся.

Скажем так. ГЭС "Альфа" строится, ГЭС "Бета" эксплуатируется, На ГЭС "Гамма" введена в эксплуатацию первая очередь, вторая строится. Тогда по варианту а) под действие закона подпадают все три ГЭС, по варианту б) только "Гамма"

Но совершенно очевидно, что неоднозначность всегда решается в пользу первой трактовки. Другими словами, *в естественных языках операция "И" относится к объединению множеств, а не их свойств, как это имеет место в математике.* 
Сравните: "Убитых нет, больных и раненых - нет". Вы можете себе представить, что имеются в виду раненые, которые к тому же еще и больные? Половине отряда руки-ноги поотрывало, у остальных - свинка и коклюш с ветрянкой, но "больных и раненых" нет.

Comment: Правильно ли я поняла? (Поправьте меня, если ошиблась). Я вас поняла так. "Речь идет обо всех сооружениях: и эксплуатируемых, и строящихся, и   о тех, которые одновременно эксплуатируются и строятся".  Если так, то я согласна.

Comment: Нет, подождите...
Вы о какой части моего теста спрашиваете? Тут такой вопрос, что немудрено и самому запутаться - и всех запутать.
Это?  
  
>Т.е. речь может идти и о всех сооружениях: эксплуатируемых либо строящихся, либо только о тех, которые одновременно и эксплуатируются и строятся. 
  
Уточняю формулировку в тексте. Вернее переделываю полностью. Так понятнее?

Спасибо, кстати.

Comment: Нет, запятой там нет. А как Вы считаете, допустимо ли с юридической точки зрения "выбирать" для себя ту формулировку, в которой более заинтересован, в случае такой грамматической неоднозначности как здесь. Спасибо Вам за подробный ответ!

Comment: Нет, с юридической точки зрения это недопустимо. Нечто подобное - да и то в весьма ограниченном виде может иметь место в уголовном судопроизводстве (разночтения трактуются в пользу обвиняемого), но никак не в гражданской  сфере.