# Неоднозначность при использовании союза "и"

Tags: однородные-члены, и

Допустим, есть такое предложение: "Вася оказался единственным учеником в классе с четверкой за тест и пятеркой за аудирование".

Какой смысл будет у этого предложения?

Я думал об этих вариантах:

1. Что Вася единственный, у кого одновременно И четверка, И пятерка (то есть единственный с такой комбинацией оценок).
2. Что Вася единственный, кто получил четверку за тест (у остальных 2/3/5) и пятерку за аудирование (у остальных 2/3/4).

Есть ли здесь вообще неоднозначность, и, если есть, с помощью каких изменений от неё избавиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Есть ли здесь вообще неоднозначность, и, если есть, с помощью каких
> изменений от неё избавиться?

Если вы не математик и не юрист, надо очень сильно захотеть, чтобы увидеть здесь что-то неоднозначное.
На самом деле тут вариант 1. Ваш вариант 2. я даже не понял сразу. Давайте не будем заморачиваться с оценками... Они сильно путают, скрывая суть.

*Вася - единственный ученик в классе, у которого папа - олигарх и мама домохозяйка.*

Найдите мне человека, которой поймет эту фразу так: в классе вообще нет других детей олигархов **и** нет других детей домохозяек. Так почему с оценками должно быть как-то иначе?

Но если уж очень сомневаетесь, замените союз "и" на "а". Все вопросы снимутся.

Вот упомянутые математики тут могут призадуматься. Здесь "единственный" выступает в роли квантора, область действия которого может либо распространяться на все объекты, связанные союзом "и", либо ограничиваться им.
И вопрос этот интересный с точки зрения семантики фраз в целом. Но этот разговор здесь откровенно не поднять.

Так что, если уж очень надо избежать даже надуманных обвинений в двусмысленности, пишите просто и ясно:

**"Вася оказался единственным учеником в классе с четверкой за тест, но пятеркой за аудирование".**
или
**"Вася оказался единственным учеником в классе с четверкой за тест и единственным с  пятеркой за аудирование".**

Надеюсь, тут никакой двусмысленности не обнаружится.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - я прочитать еще не умпел, что наваял, а вы уже отредактировали. Но все равно - спасибо.)))

Comment: Квантор единственности в математике обозначается как Э! Я в этом плохо понимаю, но готов спорить, что невозможно записать утверждение: "Вася единственный толстый среди всех и единственный длинный среди всех" с использованием только одного вхождения Э!. Вам все равно понадобиться повторить квантор Э! второй раз. В русском языке аналогично, придется повторить слово единственный два раза. Хотя в языке есть и другие возможности

Comment: @user190920 Вы неправильно понимаете. Есть еще такая вещь как скобки. Да и к чему вообще это уточнение даже безотносительно к его истинности? А спорить с непрофессионалом - не комильфо... Старая еврейская мудрость гласит, что из двух спорящих один всегда дурак, а другой подлец. ))))

Comment: Скобки не помогут, в том то и дело. Уточнение к вашему пассажу про кванторы в математике которые якобы допускают соответствующую трактовку в русском языке. Ничего они такого не допускают.

Comment: *Скобки не помогут, в том то и дело* - я даже отвечать не буду. ))))

Comment: *про кванторы в математике которые якобы допускают соответствующую трактовку в русском языке* - простите, это выше моего понимания. Давайте только не приписывать другим подобные перлы.

Comment: @user190920 все, что могй посоветовать, прочитайте последний абзац ответа - https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/15310

Comment: @behemothus: *я прочитать еще не успел...* — ха-ха, я сам потом посмотрел и удивился, что ответ такой свежий.))) А вообще, я не быстро читаю. ;)

Comment: Недавно прочитал похожее предложение и в голову почему-то пришел вариант 2. Но, как оказалось, автор имел в виду вариант 1, поэтому я и призадумался.
Спасибо за развернутый ответ.